# Alternative package manager for ubuntu terminal?

Tags: package-management, command-line

I'm looking for:

- Alternative package management to be used from my gnome-terminal (text-based method) that can be a candidate to replace apt-get and aptitude.
- Preferably one with detailed and easily read outputs, reduced command options (like perform update before a search), and go fast enough.

Does any one know a alternative package manager?

Comment: sorry i've always used gui front-ends, because my stance is that production servers should not have older packages....interested to see responses though

Answer (score 9):

The only command line tool for package management that I can think of, other than `apt-get` and `aptitude` is `dselect`. It provides an interactive (curses?) interface for doing all of the common package management tasks.

[image: dselect]

It is not installed by default so will need to be installed using one of your existing package installation tools. See [man dselect](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/dselect.1.html) for more details about how to use it.

Comment: i think he is looking for update-alternatives package mgmt tool...can you do this from dselect?

Comment: dselect can do all the usual tasks - install, remove, upgrade, update etc.

Comment: How can I use update-alternatives to see all alternatives of a command/package?

Answer (score 0):

There is alternatives.

One of them is wajig >> http://wajig.togaware.com/

Easy to use and have a nice usage experince. You may use like

```
wajig [option] [command]
```

for apt-get like usage,

or you may simply use

```
wajig
```

for doing things in its own console.